# Microsoft Teams Adpative card on clicking button how to open browser window as popup

Tags: bots, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

On clicking the button in Microsoft Teams Adaptive card how to open the browser window as a popup.

Eg: In the Teams Jira cloud app clicking the sign-in button under adaptive card opens the browser window as a popup.

[image]

I am using the below code in my adaptive card which opens the new browser tab and not as a browser window popup.

```
{
  "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
  "id": "loginId",
  "title": "Sign in",
  "url": "${url}"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour as the Action.OpenUrl in Adaptive Cards is designed to open the URL in a new browser tab or window, not as a pop-up.

To achieve your requirements, we recommend you give your feedback in [Teams Feedback Portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).

Comment: then how it is working for Teams Jira cloud app

Comment: In case of Jira cloud app it opens a pop-up window for authentication. In order to achieve that you can use the Teams JavaScript Client SDK's `authentication.authenticate()` method. This method opens a pop-up window instead of a new tab. More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/authentication/auth-tab-aad?tabs=teamsjs-v2#initiate-authentication-flow)